# grpc.WithInsecure is deprecated: use insecure.NewCredentials() instead

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

Hey I'm trying make a small test client with Go and Grpc,

```
opts := grpc.WithInsecure()
    cc, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:9950", opts)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

The `WithInsecure()` function call gives a warning:

> grpc.WithInsecure is deprecated: use insecure.NewCredentials() instead.

I'm not sure how to use this new function call is there an example somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The function [`insecure.NewCredentials`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure#NewCredentials) returns an implementation of `credentials.TransportCredentials`.

You can use it as a `DialOption` with [`grpc.WithTransportCredentials`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.40.0#WithTransportCredentials):

```
grpc.Dial(":9950", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
```

Comment: As an update as of v1.44.0 (Jan 25, 2022) it is not experimental anymore. Also, the `staticcheck` linter reports this.

Comment: where is insecure.NEwCredentials()

Comment: @MajorEccles It’s in `google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure`